# Internal working of List in c#

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain how `List<T>` works internally in C#?

```
 public List<ConvData> pdetails = new List<ConvData>();
```

How is it stored? What exactly happens when we call `pdetails.Add();`

Comment: You can just Decompile the System.Collections assembly to [see the code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/List@cs/1305376/List@cs)

Comment: Why not see the source? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9cc11588bffd57c1

Comment: Have a look http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List is implemented the same way C++'s vector, meaning the implementation allocate an array of a predefined size, fills that array, and when you want to add an element and the array is full the implementation allocate a new array, bigger, copies all values to the new array, and then adds the new value.
This results with an AVERAGE performance of O(1) when adding, but not always.

Comment: So,after adding element into the List.What Exactly the List will contain either value or reference

Comment: depends on the type of your objects, whether they are reference types or value types

Comment: ok..Now  my concept clear.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just take a look [at the reference source from Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646) and see how it works in detail.

Right now, the `Add` method looks like this:

```
// Adds the given object to the end of this list. The size of the list is
// increased by one. If required, the capacity of the list is doubled
// before adding the new element.
//
public void Add(T item) {
    if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
    _items[_size++] = item;
    _version++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It starts out like this:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;

    private T[] _items;
    [ContractPublicPropertyName("Count")]
    private int _size;
```

Note the `private T[] _items;` is how the list is stored internally.

Here's `.Add(...)`:

```
    public void Add(T item) {
        if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
        _items[_size++] = item;
        _version++;
    }
```